# EC2 User-data script is not starting my Java application

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I need to start my java application with a script,
but User Data are not working: if I start the application manually, it works.

My EC2 instance has Ubuntu

Here’s the snippet of the User Data I’m using:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ubuntu
sudo su
java -jar HelpDesk-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Data script are executed **only on the very first boot**: it seems you expect that the script will be executed at every reboot.

Comment: Hummm i undestand , Thanks, I've been trying to get it to work for a while. Any solution to get it to run that way every time I start the instance?

Comment: There’s tons of approaches on how to launch a script on startup on Linux, here’s some examples: https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up